# Does the 'counter-reset' property always have to be defined on the parent container?

Tags: html, css

My understanding is that the counter-reset is set on the parent container to define a counter. Then, you set the counter-increment with the name of the counter on each child-element you want incremented, and then of course you use the counter name for the content property to have it displayed.

But in the example given in w3schools, the counter-reset is set on a sibling, not a parent, and i can't understand how does that work out?

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section;
}


h1 {
  counter-reset: subsection;
}

h1::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "Section " counter(section) ": ";
}

h2::before {
  counter-increment: subsection;
  content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
```

```html
<body>

<h1>HTML and CSS h1</h1>
<h2>HTML Tutorial h2</h2>
<h2>CSS Tutorial h2</h2>
<h2>Bootstrap Tutorial h2</h2>
<hr>

<h1>JavaScript h1</h1>
<h2>JavaScript Tutorial h2</h2>
<h2>jQuery Tutorial h2</h2>
<h2>JSON Tutorial h2</h2>
<hr>

<h1>Server Side h1</h1>
<h2>SQL Tutorial h2</h2>
<h2>PHP Tutorial h2</h2>

</body>
```

Now, why is the counter-reset 'subsection' set on h1, but then incremented on h2? Where is the logic here? Shouldn't the counter-reset be on the parent? Why is it set on the sibling?

Also, why is it that, if you set the counter-increment on the element you want incremented, it works fine even if you don't set a counter-rest on the parent, but if you set the counter-increment on the pseudo-element, then it doesn't work?

```css
.new {
  padding-left:50px;
}

h3 {
  counter-increment: c-test;
}

h3::before {
  content: counter(c-test) " ";
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="new">
    <h3>Tokyo</h3>
    <h3>Osaka</h3>
    <h3>Nagoya</h3>
    <h3>Fukuoka</h3>
    <h3>Sapporo</h3>
</div>
```

You see here that the counter-increment is set on h3 without having a counter-rest on the parent, and it works just fine.

However, here:

```css
.new {
  padding-left:50px;
}

h3::before {
  counter-increment: c-test;
  content: counter(c-test) " ";
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="new">
    <h3>Tokyo</h3>
    <h3>Osaka</h3>
    <h3>Nagoya</h3>
    <h3>Fukuoka</h3>
    <h3>Sapporo</h3>
</div>
```

..the counter-increment is inside the pseudo-element, and it's not being incremented. Why?

If you now just set a counter-reset on the parent, it works again:

```css
.new {
  padding-left:50px;
  counter-reset:c-test;
}

h3::before {
  counter-increment: c-test;
  content: counter(c-test) " ";
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="new">
    <h3>Tokyo</h3>
    <h3>Osaka</h3>
    <h3>Nagoya</h3>
    <h3>Fukuoka</h3>
    <h3>Sapporo</h3>
</div>
```

or, if you create an h2 inside the parent, and then add the counter-reset in it, like this:

```css
.new {
  padding-left:50px;
}

h2 {
  counter-reset: c-test;
}

h3::before {
  counter-increment: c-test;
  content: counter(c-test) " ";
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="new">
    <h2>CITIES</h2>
    <h3>Tokyo</h3>
    <h3>Osaka</h3>
    <h3>Nagoya</h3>
    <h3>Fukuoka</h3>
    <h3>Sapporo</h3>
</div>
```

Why does this work? I can't understand the logic behind this property. I thought counter-reset starts the counter, or resets the counter, and it has to be in the parent.

Can somebody explain the logic behind this property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#counters)

> The scope of a counter starts at the first element in the document that has a 'counter-reset' for that counter and includes **the element's descendants and its following siblings with their descendants**. However, it does not include any elements in the scope of a counter with the same name created by a 'counter-reset' on a later sibling of the element or by a later 'counter-reset' on the same element.

And

> If 'counter-increment' or 'content' on an element or pseudo-element refers to a counter **that is not in the scope of any 'counter-reset'**, implementations should behave as though a 'counter-reset' **had reset the counter to 0** on that element or pseudo-element.

I think both of the above cover all your questions.